# Nginx server contents gzip compress not working

Tags: http, https, nginx, compression, gzip

This is the portion in my nginx.conf but i not sure why when i check with gzip compression checker or http header, the content is not compress.

https://pasify.com

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  0;
    #keepalive_requests 5;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;
    send_timeout 10m;

    # output compression saves bandwidth
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    # Disable gzip for certain browsers.
    gzip_disable MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1);

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    ## Detect when HTTPS is used
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
      default off;
      https on;
    }

    client_max_body_size 20M;


}
```

May i know what is the problem ?

Comment: if you mean of the web address, it's the place to test the server for whether got compress or not. Please tell your reason before click the button. "Close"

Comment: Pay attention that gzip will disable ``sendfile`` !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By

> gzip_disable MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1);

you've disabled gzip for almost any browser which has digits in it's User-Agent, as there are two separate regular expressions: "MSIE" and "[1-6].(?!.*SV1)".  Add quotes around or better use this instead:

> gzip_disable msie6;

See [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_disable) for details.

Comment: Sir. I changed as described but it's still not working. any idea of what possible of error ??

Comment: I see the link in question correctly serving gzipped content now. If you think it's still not working - provide details how did you test.

Comment: Yea.. it's working now =D because the tool is too old i guess, i found it's compressed with the other tools...

Answer (score 2):

the only remark I have is that http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types says that gzip_types specifies the types to be compressed in addition to text/html.
so the text/html in your gzip_types is unnecessary. If specifying it anyway is problematic I'd consider that a bug, but try removing it just to be sure.

if that isn't it can you show us what your

```
server {...}
```

block look like?

also check to make sure that there isn't anything in /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf that sets "gzip off"?

Comment: checked, this is the only file or located at etc/nginx/nginx.conf got the keyword gzip as posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration of Nginx (at least v1.4.6) has `gzip_types` line commented out. One has to uncomment it in order for listed resource types to be served compressed.